# Adding Existing Group to Custom Ribbon in Office Word 2010

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, add-in, ribbon

I am creating a custom add-in ribbon for MS Word 2010.  I wanted to know how, if possible, can I add button groups from the other native ribbon tabs to my custom tab without reprogramming/replicating those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to reference the needed controls using the correct idMso-tag for each control in your customUI xml.

A description for how to find the correct idMso for built-in controls can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29 (below "To find the idMso value for an application")

If you prefer a bunch of lists of IDs, here is one for Office 2010 to download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627