# Add group to an existing MS Office Ribbon tab

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I'm looking for a way to programatically add a group to an existing tab (e.g Developer tab in my case) of the Microsoft Office Word 2010 ribbon.

Cannot find any helpful examples on the web. Are these types of customizations allowed in MS Office 2010 and if so could you please provide any helpful links or a code sample on how I can do this

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the according ControllId to your addin's `RibbonTab`:
[image: Tab Id]

You want to use `TabDeveloper`. A full list can be obtained from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3582).

Comment: The list linked in this post is for 2007. [Click here for 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798), or [Click here for 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)

Comment: @bsx you've got those links backwards ;)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841134/adding-existing-group-to-custom-ribbon-in-office-word-2010) might be helpful in your case